# Telegram bot API and PHP/cURL

Tags: php, curl, bots, telegram

I tried connecting to the Telegram Bot API using the below code

```
<?php
//step1
$cSession = curl_init(); 
//step2
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?chat_id=***&text=Hello");
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 

curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
//step3
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
//step4
echo curl_error($cSession);
curl_close($cSession);
//step5
echo $result;
?>
```

It works perfectly on localhost but when I upload it to the server it throws the error

```
SSL: certificate subject name '*' does not match target host name 'api.telegram.org'
```

Comment: Which OS are you using on your server? Since you already disable certificate checking you might try with `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` set to 0.

Comment: I tried that and the error changed to Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. I believe that is error 400

Answer (score 0):

I think your server has some kind of SSL issue. It has a bad SSL certificate stored which is why it works on your local machine and now on your server.

This is pretty unusual.

It's hard to tell you how to proceed without knowing your server host and OS of choice. But basically you just need to remove the certificate stored for `*` (aka all hosts) because it's trying to use that ceriticate for Telegram, but Telegram has a legit certificate.